# Exception fire when trying to open the screen

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch

When I am trying to open the screen I got the following exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Grid' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.TabItem'

Any help will be appreciated.

```
partial void VouchersDetail_Created()
    {
        this.FindControl("JournalVoucher").ControlAvailable += JournalVoucher_ControlAvailable;
    }

    void JournalVoucher_ControlAvailable(object sender, ControlAvailableEventArgs e)
    {
        ((System.Windows.Controls.TabItem)e.Control).KeyUp += JournalVoucher_KeyUp;
    }

    void JournalVoucher_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.V)
        {
            if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
            {
                var tabitem = (System.Windows.Controls.TabItem)sender;
                tabitem.IsEnabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception? Look at the stack trace.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I got the exception on the below line. `((System.Windows.Controls.TabItem)e.Control).KeyUp += JournalVoucher_KeyUp;` Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that JournalVoucher is of type Grid. And you are trying to cast that to the type TabItem.

Put a breakpoint on the line and check if the event gets called more than once.

If it only gets called once than it may be enough to change the line

```
((System.Windows.Controls.TabItem)e.Control).KeyUp += JournalVoucher_KeyUp;
```

to:

```
((System.Windows.Controls.Grid)e.Control).KeyUp += JournalVoucher_KeyUp;
```

Most likely the Sender in JournalVoucher_KeyUp is also of type Grid

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of lines in your code where you try to cast an object to TabItem:

```
var tabitem = (System.Windows.Controls.TabItem)sender;
```

One of these will no doubt be the root cause!

Your code is mostly event handlers - my guess is that these are defined on a Grid.

Comment: Hi Colin
Thank you for your reply. I got the exception on the below line. `((System.Windows.Controls.TabItem)e.Control).KeyUp += JournalVoucher_KeyUp;` Is there any workaround for this?